# Load Class Dynamically Based on Database Column in Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to have multiple User classes based on the role that the User has inside our system.  For example, I would like to have a User\Standard class and a User\SystemAdmin class.  Then I can put logic specific to the user type in the class.

I'm hoping that I can do:

```
$users = User::get()
```

and

```
$user = User::find($id)
```

and have it load the correct classes.  So get `get()` call would return a `Collection` of `User\Standard`s and `User\SystemAdmin`s but I'm struggling with how this can be accomplished.

Comment: *"I want to have multiple User classes based on the role"* - That's never a good idea... A `User` is a `User`. You should use a separate `Role` model (or `role` column on your `users` table, etc.) to differentiate them. Laravel is not designed for this kind of `User` system. You _can_ make it work, but at that point, you're fighting the framework. Are you open to using a different approach, or are you required to stick with your multiple `User` model implementation?

Comment: I'm open to other options but I'm trying to keep the logic for each user separate so they're easier to maintain.

Comment: I can tell you from experience that having 2 different Models/Tables for Users is _not_ easier to maintain. I'd highly you suggest looking into Roles, Permissions, etc (Googling Laravel Roles, Laravel Permissions, etc. should show some useful packages), and try to implement something like that. Combining that with Authentication Gates, Middleware for different Roles, etc. should allow you to keep your logic nicely separated, while maintaining a single point of entry for Authorization.